# How to filter some words in a queryset

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I have a variable, which contains stock symbols. I need to split each symbol, to compute it independently.

```
print(Symbols_Splitted)

 #returns this 

["'['AAPL", 'TSLA', "MSFT']'"]
```

I need something to filter the relevant words, the pattern is always the same.

I tried this, which works but I find out an issue. Some symbols have special characters in them like "EURUSD=X", and this code remove the "=" which makes it not valid.

```
            def convertor(s):
                perfect = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', '', s)
                return perfect

            all = list(map(convertor, Symbols_Splitted))
```

So, by taking the first example I need something like this:

```
Some_function(Symbols_Splitted)

Symbols_Splitted[0]
> AAPL
Symbols_Splitted[1]
> MSFT
Symbols_Splitted[2]
> TSLA
```

**SOLUTION:**
I added = and - within the brackets so my function is now

```
            def convertor(s):
                perfect = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z-=-]+', '', s)
                return perfect

            all = list(map(convertor, Symbols_Splitted))
```

Comment: Well, apparently the pattern is _not_ always the same. Can you describe the pattern that _separates_ the parts you are interested in? Or is the input already a list and you just need to get rid of irrelevant characters? I am asking because this reads like an XY problem.

Comment: The input is already a list, which may vary, but i simply need to get rid of the irrelevant characters

Comment: You are not giving us much to work with here. You should at least try to describe the pattern you are looking for or the pattern you want to get rid of. So far, from what you showed, you could just add `=` inside the square brackets and you'll be good. But I doubt that this is the end of it.

Comment: ok this was the solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't think substitution is the optimal route to go here. I would try an define the pattern you are *interested in* instead -- the ticker symbol.

I am not entirely sure what all the valid characters in a ticker symbol are and what rules apply to those symbols. But judging from what I have read so far, it seems that the following holds:

- At least 2 characters long
- Must start and end with a latin letter or digit
- Can contain letters, digits, dots and equals signs

With those rules, we can construct the following simple pattern:

```regex
\w[\w=.]*\w
```

The Python code could look like this:

```py
import re


PATTERN_TICKER_SYMBOL = re.compile(r"\w[\w=.]*\w")


def extract_symbol(string: str) -> str:
    m = re.search(PATTERN_TICKER_SYMBOL, string)
    if m is None:
        raise ValueError(f"Cannot find ticker symbol in {string}")
    return m.group()


test_data = [
    "'['AAPL",
    "TSLA",
    "MSFT']'",
    "''''...BRK.A",
    "[][]EURUSD=X-...",
]
cleaned_data = [extract_symbol(s) for s in test_data]
print(cleaned_data)
```

Output:

```py
['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'MSFT', 'BRK.A', 'EURUSD=X']
```

With additional requirements, the pattern can be extended of course.